# Calling a variable from a javascript file returns an undefined: Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic framework and I want to call a variable from a javascript file, but it returns undefined for the variable and prints the console inside the file.

**javascript file:**

```
console.log('Hi!')
var test = "Hello";
```

**typescript file:**

```
import * as testfile from "src/assets/js/customers"

export class CustomersPage implements OnInit {
  test:any='j';
constructor (){
this.test= testfile.test;
console.log('Hello from typescript', this.test);
}

}
```

**The Result**

Hi

Hello from typescript undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export the variable from your JavaScript file for the value to be accessible inside the TypeScript file.

So inside your `"src/assets/js/customers"` file it should be

```
export var test = "Hello";
```

OR

```
var test = "Hello";
export test;
```

If this is not a default export you need to import it like

```
import * as { testfile } from "src/assets/js/customers"
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
//Dont forget to export your JS file to use in other files.

import * as testfile from "src/assets/js/customers"

export class CustomersPage implements OnInit {
  
constructor (
  public test: testfile.test
    ){}
  async ngOnInit(){
    console.log('Hello from typescript', test);
  }
}

//or

import * as testfile from "src/assets/js/customers"

export class CustomersPage implements OnInit {
  
  async ngOnInit(){
    this.test = testfile.test
    console.log('Hello from typescript', this.test);
  }
  
  test
}
```